# History of the term "early stopping"

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, references, regularization, history

Who first used "early stopping" to refer to a form of regularization by stopping training before convergence? I have attempted to search myself but I am not sure how to find the answer.

Was the term ever used in stats before neural networks for example?

Answer (score 9):

It depends on how deep you want to go. Abraham Wald was studying sequential testing and stopping criteria in [1945](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2235829). It was further studied in the 1960 and 1970s (cf [Ferguson, 1989](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Eted/210F10/References/Secretary.pdf)). In [1989 Pocock and Hughes](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0197245689900597?via%3Dihub) described using early stopping for clinical trials (I'm not sure if this is the earliest paper like this). As about first citations of using it in machine learning, the paper by [Morgan and Bourlard (1990)](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/1989/file/63923f49e5241343aa7acb6a06a751e7-Paper.pdf) is sometimes quoted, for example by [Prechelt (1997)](https://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.37.900) or [Finoff et al (1993)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0893608005801224).

Comment: I looked at the 1945, 46, 89 and 90 papers and didn't find the phrase "early stopping".  It's possible my pdf viewer can't search for the term but is it in those papers?

Comment: Just because the _concept_ was invented/discovered doesn't mean the _name_ was solidified on day 1. (Signified/signifier...)

Comment: Pocock has a paper (BMJ 1992;305:235-40) entitled "When to stop a clinical trial" which is entirely about the ethics of early stopping. Without being unkind to the statistical expertise of the BMJ and its readers it is not a specialist statistical outlet so I suspect these ideas were around for several years before that and likely before the 1989 reference you quote.

Comment: @mdewey yep, I'm not an expert in biostats, just giving it as an example.

Comment: I have now found another earlier Pocock reference https://rss.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.2307/2988097 which discusses a trial which was stopped early. That pushes the start date to 1982. To be fair the exact phrase is not mentioned but as @AryaMcCarthy mentions that does not mean the concept was not recognised.

Comment: @mdewey (and I suppose partly @Tim) I think Pocock is referring to a different meaning of "early stopping". The OP is asking about stopping during iterative optimization, before the parameters' values have converged.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy yes, OP seems to be referring to early stopping in machine learning. As I said in the first sentence, what you consider as the early references to early stopping would depend on how deep you want to go with tracking it. The ML early stopping is an descendant of the ideas and studies on early stopping in other areas.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy yes i was responding more to the second question about whether the term was used in statistics before the use to which they referred and about which I am profoundly inexpert..

Comment: This is a nice answer, and I am with you, "early stopping" has only been well defined in the literature in the context of sequential design of clinical trials ala Pocock 1973. HOWEVER, a scan of the site reveals that this is a ML technique dealing with early termination of an iterative procedure by internally monitoring the reduction in MC error.

Comment: FWIW I trained my first MLP in 1990, and early stopping was in use then (but perhaps not under that label).  It is a fairly obvious heuristic and with the rather limited amounts of computer power available back then you tended not to train non-trivial networks for longer than you had to anyway.  "Stopped training and other remedies for overfitting" by Warren Sarle was a common reference at one time https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=6305420485281481258&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5 It also criticises the methodology in Morgan and Bourlard (1990)

Comment: The comp.ai.neural-nets FAQ list may be an earlier source, but I don't know if historical versions of that have been archived anywhere.

Comment: Margan and Bourlard methodology differs from the modern early stopping in that they used their test set for validation, which is considered bad practice. The fully modern form of the technique with three sets was developed (probably independently) by Weigend, Huberman and Rumelhart (Predicting the Future: a Connectionist Approach, 1990). I found it via an old Haykin handbook (Neural Networks: a Comprehensive Foundation). Do you think you could add this info to your answer?

Comment: @ain92 probably worth that you post it as your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The earliest reference I can find is a 1997 paper as shown - PubMed is a powerful tool to analyze trends in academic litearture. I obviously can't search "early stopping" apropos of nothing because it's apparently quite intuitive to terminate any laborious procedure early when desired precision is achieved, whether in ecological sampling, chemical and biochemical processes, medical imaging, and so on.

But which terms to combine to address the specific question becomes vague, and a matter of capturing exogenous trends. Note: Cross-validation is not an algorithm which guarantees any form of "convergence". "Early stopping" according to these searches is not well defined. You may, for instance, put a "cap" on the number of iterations allowed, or allow a more generous "convergence" criterion. Regularization and cross-validation are different concepts, too. This question is tagged "machine learning" which, even itself, is a late entry to the field of methods.

Prior to ML, there are, for instance, "one-step" estimators which are estimators such as GLS, GLMs, NLMMs, non-linear least squares, etc. which are estimated from iterative processes such as EM, NR, BGFS and whose theoretical results are known. A one-step estimator merely performs one iteration of the algorithm and produces an interesting and well behaved estimator in some cases whose variance is easy to express, and provides consistent tests of hypotheses. Theoretical work on one-step estimators has been explored since the 1980s.

[image]